How to properly measure sizes of models in Blender?
I created simple cube in Blender with Dimensions 2mx2mx2m and exported it as *.stl.

When I open it in BambuStudio I get sizes of element as 2mmx2mmx2mm.

Same strange thing happens with stls I downloaded from the internet, they also show hundreds of meters for object with size 10cm
How to properly set settings to create precise objects?

STL files are "unitless". Just like maths it is just numbers and most slicers simply assume you mean millimeters.
if the objects you download are hundreds of meters big, maybe they are produced or exported in micrometers? A millimeter is 1000 micrometer, so scaling the object by 0,1% will make it the correct size, assuming that the micrometer unit thing is the case. Just play around with some scales.
some conversion scales:

micrometer to millimeter: 0,1%
millimeter to micrometer: 100000%
millimeter to inch: 3,937%
inch to millimeter: 2540%


This. Make your model 2000 units instead of 2 units, and it should work.
